# How to Animate Compass in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-animation, compass

I am building a Qibla Finder in flutter, and for that I used [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_qiblah) package. I have succeeded to built successfully, but when I change my position, qiblah position also changes abruptly, what I want is slow and animated change. And I am having difficulty in accomplish this.
Below is my code, please tell me how to implement animation in that.

```
class _QiblahCompassWidgetState extends State<QiblahCompassWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FlutterQiblah.qiblahStream,
  builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<QiblahDirection> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
      return KLoading();

    final qiblahDirection = snapshot.data!;

    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Transform.rotate(
          angle: (qiblahDirection.direction * (pi / 180) * -1),
          child: Image(
            image: ImageString.qiblahCompass,
            width: 360.w,
            height: 360.h,
          ),
        ),
        Transform.rotate(
          angle: (qiblahDirection.qiblah * (pi / 180) * -1),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Image(
            image: Get.isDarkMode
                ? ImageString.qiblahNeedleWhite
                : ImageString.qiblahNeedleBlack,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            height: 150.h,
            width: 150.w,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);}}
```

And This is my screen.
[image]

Comment: @Difficult Ranger

Comment: i love you build screen can you please share those image resourse ??